# bash command to redirect stdin in while loop (using sed)

Tags: bash, while-loop, stdin, readfile

I am trying to stdin only lines from 1 to 1000 from a file (output.txt) to a while loop.

I have tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < (sed -n 1,1000p data/output.txt)
```

Comment: It would be wise to set the interpreter explicitly, since you are running this in `bash` as `#!/bin/bash` or wherever it is installed in your machine

Answer (score 6):

Just tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < <(sed -n 1,1000p data/output.txt)
```

adding another angular bracket "<" did the trick... If someone can explain that could be interesting.

Thanks

Comment: Search for `bash` [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) and [input re-direction](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#redirecting_input)

Answer (score 3):

the part `<(` `)`, is called process substitution, it can replace a filename in a command.

fifos can also be used to do the same thing.

```
mkfifo myfifo

sed -n 1,1000p data/output.txt > myfifo &

while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < myfifo
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to pipe the output from one command to another.
If so, use a pipe:

```
sed -n 1,1000p data/output.txt | while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done
```

Or, using the right tool for the right job:

```
head -1000 data/output.txt | while read -r ; do something; done
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the while construct is in a subprocess and does not affect variables outside of its scope, whereas input from a fifo or <(…) allows modifying outside variables.